# AJAX Chat commands /broadcast <text> command?

Tags: php, oop

My AJAX chat handles commands like:

/ban name

/lock

and more.

If I use more than one word, like this:

**/broadcast hello everyone!**

Output will be:

**helloe**

My Question is:
How can I make it not wrap (cut) the text, after the command?

So when I use this command: /broadcast hello everyone, haha ha!

Output will be: **hello everyone, haha ha!**

Instead of: **helloe**

*This is the method for commands:*

```
    public function handleCommands($message, $username)
    {
        // Splits the message.
        $str = explode(' ', $message);
        // Gets every space of the message, basically this is the command that comes after the slash
        $command = substr(strrchr($str[0], '/'), 1);

        /**
        * If we have a value after the command:
        **/

        if (isset($str[1]))
        {
            $name = $str[1];
        }


        switch ($command)
        {
            case 'ban':
                if(!empty($name))
                {
                    if (ctype_alpha($name))
                    {
                        $this->ban($name, $username);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo "Syntax Error. Do not use numbers or special characters.";
                        break;  
                    }
                } 
                else 
                {
                    echo "Syntax Error. usage: /ban (User name)";
                    break;
                }
            break;              

            case 'prune':
                $this->prune($username);
            break;

            case '':
                echo 'Available commands: /ban, /prune';
            break;

            case 'lock':
                try
                {
                    $this->lockChat($username);
                }
                catch (exception $r)
                {
                    echo $r->getMessage();
                }
            break;

            case 'broadcast':
                echo $name;
            break;

            case 'unlock':
                try
                {
                    $this->unLockChat($username);
                }
                catch (exception $r)
                {
                    echo $r->getMessage();
                }
            break;              

            default:
                echo 'That command does not exist!';
            break;
        }

    }
```

Any idea?

Problem is located at this case:

```
        case 'broadcast':
                echo $name;
            break;
```

Answer (score 0):

change this line of code

```
    if (isset($str[1]))
    {
        $name = $str[1];
    }
```

to

```
   if (is_array($str)) {
      $name = array_shift($str);
      $name = implode(" ", $name);
   }
```

Comment: Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\chat\includes\class\Commands.class.php on line 56

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.
Need to set a limit to explode function:

```
$str = explode(' ', $message, 2);
```